# Unity giving errors that aren't there?

Tags: unity-game-engine, compiler-errors, unityscript

I am using unity to connect to a server using this code attached to a button click, but I am getting a lot of errors that there aren't semicolons?  Why am I getting these errors?

```
public function BTN_Connect() {  
   String message;
   BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
   Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 5552);
   DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
   BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
   message = inFromServer.readLine();
   System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + message);
   clientSocket.close();
}
```

Comment: @Barett ok, will try that to start.  Becuase in unity they have the function Start() even in the java files

Comment: @Barett actually you have to use function when coding in Unity

Comment: As Barett said, the keyword "function" is not used in Unity.

Comment: @Dahl that isn't the issue!  The issue is the fact that is if I type: String message = "Hello"; It keeps saying I don't have a semicolon!

Comment: What program are you using for this?

Comment: You don't show any errors? Please add those.